# Why the Overrided function getting called first?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I executed the following program and I am curious about the output i got in which the function output is getting printed first even if it was the variable i tried to print first.

```
class Baap{

    public int h = 4;
    public int getH(){
        System.out.println("Baap "+h); return h;
    }

}

public class Beta extends Baap{

    public int h = 44;
    public int getH(){
        System.out.println("Beta "+h); return h;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Baap b = new Beta();
        System.out.println(b.h+" "+b.getH());
        Beta bb = (Beta)b;
        System.out.println(bb.h+" "+bb.getH());
    }

}
```

The output was as follows

```
Beta 44
4 44
Beta 44
44 44
```

Can somebody help me understand why the function block gets executed first?

Comment: @Nambari, thats not what he is referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `System.out.println` line prints a `String`.

The `String` is evaluated at run-time as `b.h + " " + b.getH()`, so it concatenates `b.h`, space and the result of the method `b.getH()`, so it calls `getH()` which prints `Beta 44`, then prints the result `4 44`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, all of its parameters have to be evaluated first. In your case the only parameter to `System.out.println` is the expression `b.h + " " + b.getH()`.

Since that is still an expression, the next step is to evaluate that expression, which means to determine the value of the expression. It consists of 2 plus operators which have 3 operands. In order to evaluate the plus operators the program has to evaluate the values of the operands.

The value of `b.h` evaluates to 4, because variables are resolved statically-ish in Java. The type of the variable `b` is `Baap` so we get 4.
The next value is `" "` which is already a literal so there's nothing to do.
After that we have the function call `b.getH()`. Function calls in Java are always resolved virtually, so we actually call the function called `getH` of the `Beta` type. This function only sees its own scope, where the variable `h` declared in the class `Beta` "shadows" the one declared in the class `Baap`, meaning the `h` variable of `Baap` is hidden to every member of `Beta`.
To evaluate the function call we have to execute the function which prints "Beta 44" and returns the value 44.

Now that we have values for all 3 operators we can evaluate the expression with the + operators. This results in the String "4 44" which now gets passed to System.out.println and finally printed on the screen.